# Using .slideToggle to pull a hidden div up from the bottom

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slidetoggle

I can't seem to figure out how to reveal hidden content from the bottom up as opposed to from the top down. I've done some homework on here and came across a solution from jQuery UI, but must be implementing it wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated - new to scripting.

cheers!

Here's what I'm working with

the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#clientsOpen').click(function() {
     $('#clientsDropDown #clientsDashboard').slideToggle({ direction: "up" }, 300);
 $(this).toggleClass('clientsClose'); 
  }); // end click
});
```

the markup:

```
<div id="clientsDropDown">
<div id="clientsDashboard">
    <p id="clientsCTA">Let's make something beautiful together...<br /><a href="mailto:brockman.eric@gmail.com">brockman.eric@gmail.com</a></p>
</div><!-- /clientsDashboard -->
<p id="clientsOpen">clients</p>
</div><!-- //clientsDropDown -->
```

The style:

```
#clientsDropDown {
    bottom:0;
width: 100%;
padding-bottom:2%;
z-index: 100;
}

#clientsOpen {
background: url("images/open.png") no-repeat scroll 68px 10px #414142;
color: #ececec;
cursor: pointer;
float: left;
font-size: 26px;
margin: -2px 0 0 10%;
padding: 0 15px 2px;
text-decoration: none;
width: 63px;
}

#clientsCTA {
background:#414142;
width:100%;
color: #CCCCCC;
text-align:center;
font-size: 46px;
margin: 0;
padding: 30px 0;
text-decoration: none;

}

#clientsDropDown .clientsClose {
background-image: url(images/close.png);
}

#clientsDropDown #clientsDashboard {
display: none;  
}
```

Comment: From what I can make out, the default for `slideToggle()` is to slide upwards, thus the option `direction: up` is unneeded. If you remove it from the top answer fiddle then it still slides upwards. Furthermore, `direction` is [not even a listed option](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/#slideToggle-options) for the `slideToggle()` function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add `position:absolute;` to `#clientsDropDown`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8LXY6/)**

Or if you want "clients" to sit on top of the popup div, remove the float and position the paragraph above the dashboard div like in this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8LXY6/1/)**.

Comment: This worked beautifully, but when it slides up, it covers the content at the bottom instead of pushing the other content up to make room for it. Given that it's positioned absolutely, I suppose there's no way around that?

Comment: Right, if you position it absolutely it takes it out of the flow of the document so the other content on the page won't be pushed when it slides.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your script to:

```
$("#clientsOpen").click(function(){
    $("#clientsDashboard").slideToggle();
}, function(){
    $("#clientsDashboard").slideToggle();
});
```

Yes and of course position the container div to absolute.

Comment: ah yes! thank you @j08691, that works beautifully, had the open button at the bottom as I stole it from script I used at the top of the document, but the absolute positioning was a lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

The actual property that is changing the direction of the reveal animation is the `bottom` CSS property.  If it were changed to `top` the animation would reveal down rather than up.

Try it for `#clientsDropDown` in the previous fiddle provided and you will see it in action.