# How to load bottom section using JQuery or any other technology

Tags: jquery

How to load the section below using JQuery, if it can be achieved with JQuery?

This is the site: http://www.scottradke.com/new-gallery-1

There is a link on the bottom right with which you can load the bottom section up. I did not try anything yet, although I could use a starting point. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
/*QuickReset*/
*{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}html,body{height:100%;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}

#panel {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #cfcfff;
}

#panel-toggler {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
}

#panel-content {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  transition: 1s;
  max-height: 0;
}

#panel-checkbox:checked+#panel #panel-content {
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<input hidden type="checkbox" id="panel-checkbox">

<div id="panel" class="hide">

  <label id="panel-toggler" for="panel-checkbox">
    Click to slide toggle
  </label>

  <div id="panel-content">
    <p style="border:4px dashed #000; height:200vh;">Tall P to force scrollbars</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Bravo Roko! 3hree thumbs up for You!

Comment: Is there a way for me to add the `OVERFLOW-Y: Scroll;` to `#panel-content-inner`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple slide animation which can easily be achieved in jQuery with .slideToggle(). You can read more about this here: http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("p").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```css
p {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>slideToggle demo</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <button>Toggle</button>
  <p>
    This is the paragraph to end all paragraphs. You should feel <em>lucky</em> to have seen such a paragraph in your life. Congratulations!
  </p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I shall check this up.

Comment: This is the closest to what I wanted...: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14326318/6494366